# FB.NativeExtensions.onready only works when the page is rendered in a WebView of the native Facebook app

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

Facebook SDK throws following console error:

FB.NativeExtensions.onready only works when the page is rendered in a WebView of the native Facebook app. Test if this is the case calling FB.UA.nativeApp()
sdk.js:57

Has anyone encountered this?

I created this simple fiddle and it shows the error even by just loading FB SDK.

```
  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js,
      fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
      return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eh6bx54g/4/)

Comment: I happened tonight... I have same error, code is placed monthes ago, and tonight the error appeared

Comment: Likely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48782951