# What's this FB.NativeExtensions.onready console error related to Facebook and how can I resolve it?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, console

I've just noticed in the console I have this error, which is relating to Facebook.

The strange is though there is nothing on the page to do with Facebook, no widgets JS or anything.

I've never seen this before and have no idea what to do about it, can anyone help identify it and more importantly, how do I remove it?

> FB.NativeExtensions.onready only works when the page is rendered in a
>   WebView of the native Facebook app. Test if this is the case calling
>   FB.UA.nativeApp()

Comment: Please specify language/technology you're using in tags

Comment: @VadimKotov I didn't think that was relevant, but I've done that.

Comment: Well, php is not relevant, but wordpress is. I was not sure if it is about mobile app or web.

Comment: Wordpress is not relevant imho, I get that error just by including Facebook SDK.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1514160572216577/

Comment: @Lee its new bug from facebook. it started few hours ago. they will solve soon.! I got same error in my website from today

Answer (score 11):

It's nothing we can do.

It's a facebook bug and it should be solved soon. It appears a few hours ago.

@cbroe left us [this url](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1514160572216577), and we should follow.

Comment: Because it's nothing we can do. We have to wait for facebook devs.
I tried to beautify the js file, and found that throw error on line 6474, but what can we do with that? :)

I think the this answer is more accessible to us than that indented and hidden comment.

Comment: Problem solved (on all recent api versions): "2 hours ago · Status changed to Fixed". Same link: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1514160572216577

Answer (score 0):

Now, I ain't getting any console error from Facebook.

I hope they fixed this issue.

But, in the bug tracker, they didn't update it. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1514160572216577/