# How to solve FB.NativeExtensions.onready only works when the page is rendered in a WebView of the native Facebook app

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, console

I got and following error

```
FB.NativeExtensions.onready only works when the page is rendered in a WebView of the native Facebook app. Test if this is the case calling FB.UA.nativeApp()
j @ sdk.js:57
o @ sdk.js:140
a @ sdk.js:141
require @ sdk.js:24
require @ sdk.js:24
require @ sdk.js:24
require @ sdk.js:24
__d @ sdk.js:24
(anonymous) @ sdk.js:147
(anonymous) @ sdk.js:191
(anonymous) @ sdk.js:191
```

while working on GRAPH API 'v2.11' how can I solve this?

Here is my `init` function

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        autoLogAppEvents: true,
        status: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.11'
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function (response) {
        // Get comment count
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.remove', function (response) {
        // Get comment count
    });
}
```

Comment: A short look around the current existing questions for the `facebook` tag, and you would have found https://stackoverflow.com/q/48782951/1427878, where we already discovered that this is a current Facebook bug, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1514160572216577/